# Custom Cell in mixed Table View Controller ( how to connect outlets ? )

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I have table view controller, that has 2 types of cell. Static cell and dynamic cell. The first row is reserved for 1 static cell and the second for dynamic.

This is my code inside table view controller

```
class AddCompanyTableVC: UITableViewController {


var dataSource: [String] = ["123","123"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(CompanyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CompanyCells")

}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 1 {
        return 2
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CompanyCells", for: indexPath) as! CompanyCell

        return cell
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, indentationLevelForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: indexPath.section)
        return super.tableView(tableView, indentationLevelForRowAt: newIndexPath)
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, indentationLevelForRowAt: indexPath)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        return 100
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
}}
```

And this is code that i want to use for dynamic cell

```
class CompanyCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}}
```

The problem is that i cannot connect outlet from storyboard to CompanyCell. I checked if i set up everything in storyboard. Dynamic cell's class is CompanyCell and table view controller's class is  AddCompanyTableVC. Any idea how can i connect outlets? I want to use 4 labels in my dynamic cell .

**EDIT**
Here is the screen from storyboards.
[image]

Comment: If first cell is static then you should go with header view.

Comment: I will have more static cell in first section. At this moment i have only one , so i can add them later if everything works.

Comment: Did you set the `view` class to be your `CompanyCell` class, or only set the `File's owner` to it? You also need to connect the outlets to the view, not the owner.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your storyboard as well

Comment: I added screen from storyboard